# Redmineのフィールド情報のまっとうな取得方法について

Tags: api, rest, redmine

RedmineのAPIについて質問です。
あるプロジェクト/トラッカーに適用されているカスタムフィールドを取得する際にはどのような方法を手段がありますでしょうか？

現状専用のAPIがない認識で、
以下のAPIでチケット情報を取得してカスタムフィールドの情報を読み込む他ない認識です。

[GET /issues.[format]](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_Issues)

この方法だと残念ながらチケット件数が０の場合にフィールド情報が取得できません。
できれば０件でもフィールド情報が取得できる方法を教えていただきたく、ご質問させていただいております。

Comment: プロジェクト情報取得APIとカスタムフィールド情報取得APIを利用し、トラッカーのIDやカスタムフィールドのIDを突き合わせて合致するものをプロジェクト／トラッカーのカスタムフィールドとする、といったところでしょうか？

プロジェクト情報取得API → http://localhost:3000/projects/プロジェクト名.xml?include=trackers,issue_custom_fields
カスタムフィールド情報取得API → http://localhost:3000/custom_fields.xml
ついでに、トラッカーの標準フィールド情報 → http://localhost:3000/trackers.xml

Answer (score 1):

管理者権限で`GET /custom_fields.xml`することで、全プロジェクトのカスタムフィールドの情報(項目名や選択肢の種類など)を取得できます。
[Custom Fields](https://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_CustomFields)

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。
ただ、そちらのAPIではどのトラッカーで利用されているかについては記述されておりますが、どのプロジェクトに紐づいているかについては記述されません。
プロジェクト／トラッカーに紐づいたフィールド情報が欲しい場合はどのAPIを利用しますでしょうか？（トラッカーAPIには標準フィールドのみ記述があり、カスタムフィールド情報はありません。）

Answer (score 0):

payanecoさんはおっしゃるように、RedmineのRestAPIそのものでは、/custom_fields.[format]からGETするしかなく管理者権限が必要でした。

管理者権限のないユーザーでは、ダミーのプレイべートissueを作成してカスタムフィールドの定義を取得してから削除する方法をとりました。